# join same table columns

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am working with android SQLite, and trying to combine same table data

My table looks like:

```
a  b  c
-------
3  5  0
3  3  0
3  7  1
4  6  0
4  8  1
```

---

```
3  8  7
4  6  8
```

for each 'a' where 'c'=0 make sum of 'b' and where 'c'=1 make sum of 'b'.

I tried inner join and more joins but none of them gave me the right answer.

Comment: where last bit 0 make sum and where last bit 1 make sum. for any misunderstandings

Comment: Sorry, your question is still not very clear. Do you want to add the columns where the last number is the same? Please give also the name of the columns that you use.

Comment: the result columns as expected are : 'a' , (sum('b') where c=0) , (sum('b') where c=1);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a simple `GROUP BY` and a `SUM`, like this:

```
SELECT
    a
,   SUM(CASE c WHEN 0 THEN b ELSE 0 END) as sum_0
,   SUM(CASE c WHEN 1 THEN b ELSE 0 END) as sum_1
FROM myTable
GROUP BY a
```

[Demo on sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/827a8/5)